# color management in blender 3.3

Tags: color-management

I recently update to blender3.3, but I find that there isn't any choice in color management. Then, how do I change my render color to high contrast in the new version?

[image]

Comment: Couple of questions (based on another post) - are you using a portable version of blender? Also, have you installed blender in a OneDrive folder? - This may be an unsolved bug - see here - https://developer.blender.org/T82081

Comment: Yes, I only download the portable version, but not in the OneDrive folder.

Comment: From the thread I linked, It seems that the problem only affects portable versions (I think one comment even suggests that installing a non-portable version fixes the OCIO path problem that seems to cause this, thus "fixing" the portable install as well). Maybe it's worth giving the standard (non-portable) version an install and see if it works and/or fixes anything.